# inherit in dreamweavers Fluid Grid Layout

Tags: responsive, dreamweaver, fluid-layout

Im using Dreamweaver's Fluid Grid Layout to build a responsive website. The issue I am having is when I go and change the CSS code for the smallest browser sizes such as a mobile device the tablet and desktop size changes as well. Basically it inherits the mobile size settings. I don't want it to inherit and characteristics. Is there a way to stop this from happening?